# Snap Geometry to Layer (Line to Point) does not snap all lines within the tolerance limit

Tags: qgis, point, line, snapping

I've been using QGIS 3.14 version to snap geometries to layer.

[image: Parameters: Tolerance is 0.6m and behaviour: prefer aligning nodes, insert extra vertices where required]

When I try to run this, I have to fix the geometry first before I run select by location.

I checked the output, most are correct but there are lines that did not snap correctly within the tolerance limit I set like this: (The distance in the photo is not even 0.001)

[image]

Is the manual way the only way to fix this?

Comment: Is the line on the last picture the original line or the line output of the process ?

Comment: Have you experimented with the `behavior` drop down list?

Comment: @LouisCottereau it's the output of the process

Comment: @Erik yep. in this particular line, it still does not move.

Comment: If feel like `Prefer closest point, insert extra vertices where required` should remedy your problem, but I can't verify this without example data.

Comment: I recall similar results recently in fixing a line layer for the polygonize tool, which lacks a tolerance parameter. I ran a v.clean which snapped, but in a situation like the above it moved the line to the point so I decided to instead manually fix it.  But that required putting a vertice in on the line first, then moving the endpoint aways and then snapping it to the vertice.  I figured the distance is within the layer's tolerance and is thus being treated as being the same. If you zoom in close enough you can also introduce apparent discrepancies that are from the limits of the display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snapping is only done relative to the original line:
[image]
[image]
This snapping is set to 0.220 meters and as you can see some points are really close to the snapped line but more than 0.220 meters away from the original line so the line doesn't snap to them.

[image]
[image]